# Is there a way to not specify a specifier in printf?

Tags: c, printf

The people over at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) give the reference for printf as so:
`printf("%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier", "Message");`
but if I wanted to to prepend some spaces, I would have to use `%[number of spaces]s, "" ...etc` is there a clearer way to prepend spaces, without clunkily prepending empty strings?

Comment: What is the range of _number of spaces_?  Always 1 or more?  Could negative values occur and what would happen then?   Might it be large like 4000 or more?

Comment: @chux not a static number of spaces, but also not a large number like 4000.

Comment: @chux always positive, although it brings up the question of what happens if `printf` is given a negative number

Comment: With `printf("%*s", width, "Message");`, `width` is the _minimum_ width, so `printf("%*s", -1, "Message");` prints `"Message"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `*` to specify the total width.  No  prepended empty strings.

```
const char *message = "Message";
int number_of_spaces = 3;
int width = number_of_spaces + strlen(message);

printf("<%*s>\n", width, message);
```

Output

```
<   Message>
```

Comment: "is there a clearer way to prepend spaces, without clunkily prepending empty strings" Yours is the only real answer here :)

Comment: @Daniel Hmm, Just different takes on OP posts.  The possibilities and limitations are not alway so clear.  Could even use `printf("%*c", n, ' ');` to print `n` spaces (OP wants no `""` and `n` is positive) - this may be _cheating_.

Comment: BTW: Do not use `printf("<%*s>\n", number_of_spaces + strlen(message), message);`.  Wrong type for width.  Could use `printf("<%*s>\n", (int) (number_of_spaces + strlen(message)), message);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf("%15s", "");` to print just 15 spaces.

You can use `printf("%15s%d\n", "", number);` to print a number with 15 spaces prepended to the output.

Comment: This still encounters the problem of having to have the `,"",`, which I find aggravating, since if an argument is empty, you should be able to write your code without it.